# How to get CPU and Memory usage in Apache Cordova?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, ionic2, apache-cordova

I need to get the CPU and Memory usage of my Apache Cordova App.
Is there a way to do that? (by coding)

I've implemented getFreeDiskSpace method already. (is there a getTotalDiskSpace method or similar?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-system-cpu 
https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-system-memory

might be a good starting point